# Compare two objects of type Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ssas, adomd.net

I have two `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.MajorObject` objects (e. g. `Database`) and wan't to check whether they are equal (basically I wan't to decide whether I have to process the database or update / redeploy it).

The only way I found is to serialize the databases to XML using the `Utils.Serialize` method and use `XmlDiff` to compare both XMLs. But this seems a little bit awkward to me.

Is there any **other way to compare these two objects**?

*Im using ADOMD.NET with Microsoft.AnalysisService.dll 11.0.0.0 in C#*

Answer (score 1):

[SSAS Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/experimental-tools/ssas-compare/) is a really helpful comparison tool from Redgate. It lets you compare two SSAS cubes and then script the differences so you can copy them to an XMLA query window to deploy the changes.

> You can deploy changes from one SSAS database to another, deliver updates from test to production, and save time comparing and processing.